# How would one set up the equations for this homeomorphism described in Munkres' Topology pg. 339?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm having a hard time writing in equations the map for $f$ as described in the paragraph from the text book below, and additionally would like to know that if we're trying to prove $S^1 \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to $D$ then why are we showing $C_1 \times C_2$ homeomorphic to $D$?

[image]

Comment: The reason that the author is showing $C_1\times C_2$ is homeomorphic to $D$ is because it is easier to see the homeomorphism that way, and $C_1\times C_2$ is homeomorphic to ${\Bbb S}^1\times {\Bbb S}^1$ trivially.

Comment: @Noah Ok, I see now that it is indeed trivial. Only need help with setting up the equation for now.

Comment: Hint: At first, ignore that this is about the torus and figure out the map $\mathbb{R}^3\times S^1\to\mathbb{R}^3$ (or rather $\mathbb{R}^3\times C_2\to \mathbb{R}^3$) which *rotates $\mathbb{R}^3$ along $C_2$* and then just restrict the map to $C_1\times C_2$.